# trying to import cv2 on raspbrry pi. import error

Tags: python, opencv, pi

I have been having huge isuess h intalling opencv on a raspberry pi, i believe it has poperly installed thie but will not import when testing `import cv2` in python.

below is the error i got when trying to import cv2 using geany.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libImath-2_2.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

please help me fix this error, i have been trying to get this working for 2 weeks.

I tried the solution below

"Install the following packages with apt-get:
libilmbase-dev
libopenexr-dev
libgstreamer1.0-dev
"
and got the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libavresample.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi/issues/18

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure I've found the solution from the commented link.
Manually installing libraries using `apt get` as they can't be found solves the issue.